# Hibernate : simulate before flushing

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

At one point in our app, one can edit some complex data, hit *save* and get some calculus results back.

Now we would like user to be able to get those results without actually saving data into DB - allowing user to cancel action if results aren't ok.
Is there any way to do so with Hibernate (or any other method / tool / workflow) ? A kind of "create a session without allowing flushing" ?

Our business services heavily rely on DAOs to do those computations - at this time, only thing we can think of is to actually persist modified data, compute results, then delete temp data and send results back. If user confirms he wants to proceed, real data are saved and calculus is processed once again (with the risk of data having been modified in the meantime..)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a session that can leave so long can lead you to connection pool problems.

To do so, you can just return the entity without being saved and have another entry to your system which allows you to save the received entity (with some previous validation).

This way, you avoid having a client session which contains transition data; you manage complete entities: after the computation you return the complete entity, and after the client validation you receive a complete entity.

Just be aware that you may refresh/reattach your entity to the hibernate session before saving it because you can have another thread/client which modified it during the client validation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. Well, my question isn't precise enough I realize : the object I have to save is not sent directly by the client, I have a whole process and several entities impacted before actually saving it (and then doing computation). So this is not an option.

Comment: But you still have a manual action to save it? The time between the entity is modified and the entity is saved can be huge, isn't it? If this is true, you must avoid having them in the hibernate session. If there are multiple entities, you should consider to use a wrapper and then send them in a DTO or store them in a context holder.

Comment: Time can be huge indeed, and I get I can't keep objects in session that long - that's why I'm asking about an alternative method. Thank you for the DTO / context holder trail, I'll look into that.